# Error when packaging eel project to an exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, eel

I am building an python project with Eel, and I'm trying to package my program to an exe with PyInstaller as instructed in the [documentation](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel#building-distributable-binary-with-pyinstaller). However, I get the following error when I open the .exe:

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import eel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "bottle.py", line 73, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I tried to use auto py-to-exe instead of Pyinstaller, but I got the same error. Finally, I tried to package the [Eello world](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel/tree/master/examples/01%20-%20hello_world) example from the Eel documentation to see if it was my program that was the issue, but I still got the same error. I found a [similiar problem](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel/issues/68) in a github issue, but I fail to see what I should attach to --add-data.

I am running Python 3.10.8 and Eel 0.14.0. I've now tried python 3.8.9 and python 3.9.13 without luck.

**Update**

Upon further investigation, I discovered that the error only occours when I attach `--noconsole` at the end of my cmd `python -m eel hello.py web --onefile --noconsole` . However, I want my app to work without a visible console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the libraries you are using is attempting to write to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`, which are set to `None` when you run pyinstaller with  `--windowed` option.

You need to explicitly set sys.stderr and sys.stdout in your programs code as early as possible to a writeable object like an open file or an `io` buffer.

for example:

```
import sys

outfile = open("logfile.txt", "wt")
sys.stderr = outfile
sys.stdout = outfile
```